# How Oracle executes data from cache for subsequent (same/ subset) of queires

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, caching, oracle11g, query-performance

I am using Oracle 11g R2 for the following question ,although the same could be true for SQL Server and other databases.

If we have  a main select  without where

F1, F2 , F3  -> execute -> result come from DB [Q1]

> Select F1,F2, F3 from Table1

Now change the select and remove F3

F1, F2  -> execute -> result come from DB

- should come from cache as of sub set please comment

> Select F1,F2 from Table1

- How can i confirm while running above queries that oracle return the results from cache.
- Consider following cases as well,

> Select F1,max(F2), F3 from Table1  ( Super Set)
>
> Select F1, F3 from Table1  (Sub Set not exactly but at least it seems.)

Now if there is some aggregation applies for instance, Sum(F1), Max(F2) , then how oracle can make decisions that sub sets of such queries will come from cache.

I want to make a system , Windows App for instance ,  that will store the fetched data on disk and if the cache key matches through some mechanism ,  system get the result from cache for subsequent queries instead of executing on database. How can i find the best way for selecting the subsets so to enhance the performance?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misconceptions how the oracle buffer cache works. It's an internal decision what data is cached in the buffer cache and what not. If the information in the buffer cache is used depends on the scn associated with the query (check how the consistent read mechanism works). This information is also not returned as part of the query results. Which blocks are currently cached in the buffer cache can be queried with the help of V$ queries.

Full table scans are generally not cached or only for a very brief period of time.

The best approach is to have a look at materialized views with subqueries.

Comment: The way oracle fetched data from cache in case of subset of previously executed and cached query,   could be of interest.  Idea is to cache[custom build system using c#.net]  the complete oracle query ( SELECT clause, where clause, group by , etc. )  and resulted data , in a way that , it'll serve the subset from same cache instead of re-execution. Consider the case of querying on star schema of millions records .

Comment: Query results are not cached in the server (I highly recommend you get to know how oracle uses the database cache), database blocks are. However there exists the option to use query result cache.